# Thread Safety with singletons

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, jakarta-ee, thread-safety

So lets say I have a singleton I create with spring, the MyWebService.
MyWebService's goal is to return a MyObject.

**EDIT:** When I hand in a non-threadsafe Object SomeBuilder and I create objects MyObject with it, I guess that's dangerous. But: If I hand in factories who, on each method call each time instantiate a new SomeBuilder object, I guess I'm on the safe side?

```
@Webservice
public class MyWebService {
private final SomeFactory someFactory;
private final SomeBuilder someBuilder;

  public MyWebService(SomeFactory someFactory, SomeBuilder someBuilder){
    this.someFactory=someFactory;
    this.someBuilder=someBuilder;
   }
    public MyObject getSomeObject(SomeArgs someArgs){
    //this is threadsafe?
   SomeBuilder newlyCreatedBuilder=  someFactory.createObjectBuilder();
return   newlyCreatedBuilder.getMyObject(someArgs);


//where as this is dangerous?
return someBuilder.getMyObject(someArgs);

}
}
```

Comment: [Singleton Considered Evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonsAreEvil)

Comment: @Martin Spamer I think the singleton is an antipattern, as long as it is implemented with the singleton pattern by hand. using it with dependency injection is a different story. E.g. avoiding the instance field of a class in the singleton.  And writing webservices not as singeltons - well if that is possible, please give me a hint

Comment: As a general rule construct the object as required. If the object is expensive to build look it up from a resource pool, if it is very expensive to construct or needs to persist state use a EJB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's okay to use references to factories or any other java classes in a singleton as long as those other implementations are also threadsafe.

Comment: The question was: is it safe to use factories in case, in my example the MyObjectBuilder, is NOT threadsafe? To my understanding I am creating a new object MyObject in every access to getMyObject. getMyObject instanciates MyObject from a method scoped Object: MyObjectBuilder, thus it seems to me, it is threadsafe. Whereas the different approach, using a field (someClass) which creates MyObject and is shared by all accesses, seems not threadsafe.I updated my questions

Comment: I was suggested to review my question: well your answer just says - "if everything you use is threadsafe - you will be threadsafe". That's trolling, sir ;-)